# Find the solution by series $y(x)$ and check that the series converges for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know if I have done the exercise correctly, if the expression $y(x)$ is correct? or is there another way to place it?
I also need help to prove that the series converges for all $x$, please.

Let the ED be:
$y" - \beta xy' =0$

$\beta =8$

Find the solution by series $y(x)$ and check that the series converges for all $x$

Assuming that $y$ is a power series convergent on an interval we will have:

$y=\displaystyle\sum _{i=0}^\infty{c_ix^i}$

Derivatively we have:

$y'=\displaystyle\sum _{i=1}^\infty{ic_ix^{i-1}}=\displaystyle\sum _{j=0}^\infty{(j+1)c_{j+ 1}x^j}$ index change $j=i-1$

$y''=\displaystyle\sum _{j=1}^\infty{j(j+1)c_{j+1}x^{j-1}}=\displaystyle\sum _{k=0} ^\infty{(k+1)(k+2)c_{k+2}x^k}$ index change $k=j-1$

Why are the expressions $y'$ and $y''$ valid as a power series?

These power series must comply with the differential equation, so standardizing the index we have:

$\displaystyle\sum _{j=0}^\infty{(j+1)(j+2)c_{j+2}x^j}-8x \displaystyle\sum _{j=0}^\infty {(j+1)c_{j+1}x^j}=0\Rightarrow{\displaystyle\sum _{j=0}^\infty{(j+1)(j+2)c_{j+2} x^j}-\displaystyle\sum _{j=0}^\infty{8(j+1)c_{j+1}x^{j+1}}=0}$

Changing the index of the second expression $k=j+1$ gives that the differential equation takes this form:

$\displaystyle\sum _{j=0}^\infty{(j+1)(j+2)c_{j+2}x^j}-\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^\infty{ 8(k)c_kx^k}=0$

Standardizing the indices we have:

$2c_2+\displaystyle\sum _{j=1}^\infty{((j+1)(j+2)c_{j+2}-8(j)c_j)x^j}=0$

This will only happen if:

$2c_2=0$

$(j+1)(j+2)c_{j+2}-8(j)c_j=0$ Where j=1,2,..

I have left
$c_{j+2}= \displaystyle\frac{8(j)}{(j+1)(j+2)}c_j$

$j=1$

$c_3=\displaystyle\frac{8}{3(2)}c_1$

$j=2$

$c_4= \displaystyle\frac{8*2}{4*3}c_2$

$j=3$

$c_5=\displaystyle\frac{8^2(3)(1)}{5(4)3(2)}c_1$

$j=4$

$c_6= \displaystyle\frac{8^2(4)(2)}{6*5*4*3}c_2$

$j=5$

$c_7=\displaystyle\frac{8^3 (5)(3)(1)}{7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)}c_1$

$j=6$

$c_8= \displaystyle\frac{8^3(6)(4)(2)}{8*7*6*5*4*3}c_2$

$j=7$

$c_9=\displaystyle\frac{8^4 (7)(5)(3)(1)}{(9)(8)7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)}c_1$

$y(x)={c_0+c_1}\left(x+\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{8^k\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}(2j-1)}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** The product can be written using a ratio of factorials. For example:
$$c_9=\frac{8^4\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1}{9\cdot 8\cdot...\cdot1}c_1=\frac{8^4\cdot 7\cdot6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{(9\cdot 8\cdot...\cdot1)(6\cdot 4\cdot2)}c_1$$
In the term $6\cdot 4\cdot 2$ we get a $2$ factor from each number, so $$6\cdot 4\cdot 2=2^3\cdot 3\cdot2\cdot 1$$
So $$c_9=\frac{8^4\cdot 7!}{9!\cdot 2^3\cdot 3!}c_1$$
In the general case $$c_{2k+1}=2\frac{4^{k}(2k-1)!}{(2k+1)!(k-1)!}c_1$$
Let's check (this is the step for induction):

$$
c_{2k+1}=2\frac{4^k(2k-1)!}{(2k+1)!(k-1)!}c_1\\=2\frac{4(2k-1)(2k-2)}{(2k+1)(2k)(k-1)}\frac{4^{k-1}(2k-3)!}{(2k-1)!(k-2)!}c_1\\=8\frac{2k-1}{(2k+1)(2k)}c_{2k-1}
$$
Using $j=2k-1$, we get $$c_{j+2}=\frac{8j}{(j+2)(j+1)}c_j$$

Now what about convergence? The actual value of the sum has some expression including the [erfi function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html). For simplicity, assume $x>0$, $c_0=0$, and $c_1=1$. Then
$$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$$
Since all the terms are positive for a given $x$, the partial sum is always increasing with adding more terms. We want to see that the sum is less than a know convergent sum.
$$y<\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k}{k!}x^{2k}x=xe^{4x^2}$$
The increasing sequence of partial sum is bounded above by the $xe^{4x^2}$, so it is convergent

Comment: How do I get the previous terms so that they look like this example you gave me? Now how do we prove that the series converges for all x?

Comment: Note that I had a small error in the power of $4$. You don't care about $c_{2k}$, since all of them are $0$. As for the odd terms, just follow the same procedure. You can prove the rest of the terms by induction. I will add this step to my answer. Also, I will add something about convergence